# react native usb printer library not working

Tags: android, react-native, printing

- I'm testing a printer library according to a post from [here](https://mobikul.com/usb-printer-in-react-native-android-app/)  , but after running npm install and linking the library with *react-native link react-native-usb-printer*, whenever i react-native run-android it resulted in errors as shown in the screenshot below (It will go back to normal after i npm unlink the library from my project). Why? What is the solution?
- What is your recommendeded library for react native USB printers? I'm working on a POS app, need to use a printer..

[image: Error messages]

Comment: Which version of react-native are you using?
also can you post the output of ./gradlew app:dependencies

Comment: @BhaskarGyanVardhan react-native version 0.59.5, i cannot run /gradlew app:dependencies on windows command prompt. Attempt to run /gradlew will resulted in :  '/gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

1. As the error message clearly tells the "allowBackup" is presented in two different AndroidManifest.xml files, one the original XML file inside your "C:/Users/Romie Ganter/reactNAvigation/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" and also in XML file inside your library file, you can check its existence here https://github.com/bondwp/react-native-usb-printer/blob/master/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml or in "C:/Users/Romie Ganter/reactNAvigation/node_modules/react-native-usb-printer/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml". The solution is simply removing allowBackup from one of these two places, and your code should be working fine.
2. A great reference for finding react-native libraries is https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native. I briefly checked it out and I didn't find any printer related libraries there, I also check at your mentioned react-native-usb-printer library and I found two problems in it a)It seems abandoned (last update was for 2 years ago) and b)There is only an android folder inside and no ios folder, in disguise it uses escpos-printer-toolkit library so maybe iOS will be supported, I'm not sure, but nonetheless iOs support will be shaky

It seems React-Native community is not so keen on printer functionality so your best option is through something else.

EDIT: meanwhile I was able to find https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer, It seems that it is updated, supports both Android and iOs and have a decent number of stars.